# Getting an Error - Creating default object from empty value in Laravel5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am getting an error while updating data of logged in user in the database.

> Creating default object from empty value

Here are my Controller code:

```
public function updateProfile(Request $req) {
    $name =  Session::get('admin-name');
    //$user = DB::table('admin')->where('name',$name)->first();

    $user = Admin::where('name', $name)->first();
    //return dd($user);
    //return dd($req->input('admin-name'));

    if($req->input('admin-name')!= null) {
        $user->name = $req->input('admin-name');
      //  return dd($user->name);    
    }

    if($req->input('admin-email')!= null) {
        $user->email = $req->input('admin-email');
    }
    if($req->input('admin-address')!= null) {
        $user->email = $req->input('admin-address');
    }
    if($req->input('admin-mobile')!= null) {
        $user->mobile = $req->input('admin-mobile');
    }
    if($req->input('admin-dob')!= null) {
        $user->dob = $req->input('admin-dob');
    }
    $user->save();
    return redirect('admin-profile')->with('update-response','Profile Updated successfully');}
```

When i tried `return dd($user);` i am getting 'null'.
and when using 'return dd($name);' Screenshot is attached with database.

[image: Output of return dd($name[![screenshot of database])][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eXE4.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eXE4.png)

Comment: there is no data exists in your database with that id, recheck your user data

Comment: but user is already logged in. And I have retrieved it through the Session

Comment: how you are accessing session user?? and what `dd($name)` gives??

Comment: from profile page which open when user logged in

Comment: and when i use dd($name); it shows user name.

Comment: so you have data in admin table with that name?? please show the output of `dd($name)` and add a screenshot from your database where this data exists

Comment: yes i have the data.

Comment: and it would be good if you add admin model also

Comment: ok i am doing that.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot there's no admin table...

Comment: Actually it is hidden by mistake. But it is there you can see that at the top.

Comment: and what `dd($name)` gives you??

Comment: I have attached the screenshot. Name of the logged in user.

Comment: i don't see any records with `Chris Patt`

Comment: It is there id= 363

Comment: try `dd(Admin::where('id', 363)->first());` and see what happens

Comment: got the same return - name of the user with id 363

Comment: sorry. Its not the user name, instead I have got details of table

Comment: may be its getting some additional space

Comment: try this `Admin::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();`

Comment: Admin {#206 ▼
  +table: "admin"
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:10 [▶]
  #original: array:10 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}